# Java output double numbers in exponential format

Tags: java, double, string-formatting, exponential

I have some double numbers that are outputted with this format:

```
Format.String("%1.4e",doubleNumber);
```

The result is `1.123456e+03`. How can I set the number of cipher of exponent for getting this format:

```
1.123456e+003
```

I would have always 3 cipher after `e` symbol.
Thank you

---

UPDATE 1:

I have partially resolved:

```
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000E000");
```

System.out.println( formatter.format(doubleNumber) );

Now the number has always the format

```
1.123456e0xx
```

or

```
1.123456e-0xx
```

But it's not all resolved. I would have always printed the sign:

```
1.123456e+0xx or 1.123456e-0xx
```

How can I do?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Check tihs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424792/java-decimalformat-creates-error-when-enforcing-exponent-sign

Comment: thank you @TDG, I used this solution

Comment: String.Format not Format.String btw.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @TDG

```
  private String formatter(double number){
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000E000");
    String fnumber = formatter.format(number);
    if (!fnumber.contains("E-")) { //don't blast a negative sign
        fnumber = fnumber.replace("E", "E+");
    }
    return fnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do that, you'd have to do it yourself.

Easiest would be to format like you did and then add the extra zeroes, if needed.

---

Also, it's `String.format`, not `Format.String`, and the `"%1.4e"` format you gave will result in `1.1235e+03`, not `1.123456e+03`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I can see in the `String` or `Formatter` JavaDoc that allows you to do this directly. So I think you'll have to resort to some bit twiddling.

```
long exponentMask = 0x7ff0000000000000L; // per JavaDoc for Double
// the exponent is in bits 62-52, so I'm thinking a right-shift by 52
// bits would work. But I could be off by one.
int shiftExponentBy = 52;
long myDoubleAsLong = Double.doubleToLongBits(doubleNumber);
long rawExponent = myDoubleAsLong & exponentMask;
long shiftedExponent = rawExponent >> shiftExponentBy;
```

That gives you the exponent by itself. You should be able to extract the significand in a similar manner, then format each separately.

## Update 1

It seems as though your Update 1 results in the same problem, just expressed differently. You need to format the exponent separately from the significand. `DecimalFormat` allows a positive pattern and a different negative pattern, but those are for positive and negative significands. You'd need a variant on those that allows for positive and negative exponents. I don't see any such thing. I'm standing by my original answer.